# install issues with ubuntu 12.04 on emachine

Tags: system-installation

I am starting with a blank drive... trying to install 12.04 system gets to downloading files gets to file 12 of 45 and then blanks the screen and takes me back to the "desktop" without finishing the install. can anyone give me an idea on how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is occurring while the install is updating files online, then run the install without any internet connection.  It will run and install fine, and you run can the updates later when the system is fully installed and running correctly.  Problems with network connections or other things that may be causing you issues will then be easier to diagnose and fix.